# Touch all associated models on CRUD

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a 2-level nested models:

```
country <- state <- city
```

Currently, in each controller, upon all CRUD operation, I will find its parent model and runs the `.touch` for each model. For example:

```
# cities_controller.rb
def update
  @state = State.find(params[:state_id])
  @country = Country.find(@state.id)
  ...
  @state.touch
  @country.touch
end
```

For each action in `state`, `city`, I would touch its parent (and its parent's parent) whenever CRUD is completed successfully.

Is there any DRYer way to do this? I know about `autosave` option, but it only works for newly created associated record. I want to include destroyed, updated record also. If one `city` is changed, it's `state` and `country` will also be timestamped to reflect something has been changed.

Many thanks.

Comment: Keep in mind, that code doesn't belong to a controller, it belongs to the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I prefer to rewrite the `touch` function in this there models.

```rb
class State < ActiveRecord:Base
  def touch
    self.updated_at = Time.now
    self.state.touch
  end
end

class City < ActiveRecord:Base
  def touch
    self.updated_at = Time.now
    self.state.touch
  end
end
```